# Trying to set up Gmail "send mail as" SMTP mail function

Tags: postfix, smtp, centos7, gmail, virtualmin

Alright, so I've come here as a last resort hoping to find that last bit of help I need to solve this. I've spent the last two days scouring for answers without actually getting anything direct. First off, I'm an amateur at best, and this is all new territory for me when trying to understand these things. I'll try my best to describe my issue.

On my current virtual server, I'm using Centos 7 with virtualmin installed. I've set up the email accounts just fine, and they work well. (I can login using roundcube to send and receive mail just fine as well).

As a convenience to the people who would be using those email accounts, I was trying to do a "send mail as:" through gmail so that they could reply to email coming it as those addresses (as opposed to their own personal gmail).

I keep getting the "domain name not found" error when using smtp.domain.com. I've double checked to make sure I have the correct username and password (which I do), and tried a couple things to see if anything has worked. Here's what I've done so far, and the fields Gmail is asking for.

> SMTP Server: smtp.domain.com 
>    Username: _________ 
>    Password: __________
>    Port: 25, 465, 587 (as expected) 
>    Secured connection using SSL 
>    Secured connection using TLS

1. uncommented appropriate lines in the master.cf file
2. created SSL cert and copied it over to postfix (and dovecot for good measure)
3. restarted servers after editing (of course)
4. used the login information with port 465 using SSL and mail.domain.com instead of smtp.domain.com, and it gave me a "too slow to respond" error, so that was different
   tested connection using "telnet smtp.domain.com (and any of the three ports)" but I don't think I'm doing it right since it's giving me "unable to resolve host"

   - if that is what's supposed to be coming back, I guess those ports aren't open? In which case, how do I open them since nothing stood out in the master and main.cf files in postfix?
     I've seen where you might have to add some lines to allow google to connect via SMTP? Not sure on that.
5. I've done a - netstat -an | grep on all the ports and they all seem to be listening from what I can tell.
6. Tried another round of mail.domain.com on ports 465 and 587 using TLS. Got a new error. 
   "Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
   [Server response: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure code(535) ]"

   - Triple checked my login/password just to make sure
   - Looked around for solutions to that error. No dice.

Anyway, that's what I have so far. It feels like I'm just missing something small in order to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's a look at the master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp    inet    n   -   n   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps   inet    n   -   n   -   -   smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
submission  inet    n   -   n   -   -   smtpd -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

Here's postconf -n (based on what people want from looking at other issues)

```
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, www.domain.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

doveconf -n:

```
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.1.5-x86_64-linode61 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)  
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap pop3
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Here's my smtpd.config (located in etc/sasl2)

```
    pwcheck_method: saslauthd
    mech_list: plain login
```

If you need anything else. Let me know. The errors I got in the master cf are probably a big blaring red flag that I didn't uncomment the right lines or something.

I did find this along my way while searching on a solution for those errors on configuring postfix. Would any of it apply to what I need done or missing?

http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/

Comment: You need to step back a bit and explain what you want to do to people who haven't spend their holiday weekend trying to get this (what?) to run. What is this "send mail as" function? Where exactly are you trying to configure what? What part exactly is not working and how does it fail?

Comment: Providing information about your current architecture(where your postfix server is and from where are you testing it from),some sample domain/email account names to better understand what you are trying to do/achieve and obviously postfix error logs will help us to help you better.

Comment: @ Sven - I'm just trying to allow certain people to use their gmail accounts to send email without having to log in directly to something like roundcube or squirrelmail. I can easily have them use POP3, but this is more of a convenience thing and just something that has bugged me as to why I can't get it to work
@clement I'm using a Linode virtual server based off Centos 7 if that's what you're getting at. How do I get the postfix error logs?